# Is there a way to change the GTK theme for applications run as superuser on KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, themes, gtk

When I run GTK applications on KDE, they use the QtCurve theme that matches my color and font scheme as configured in the KDE System Settings application.

However GTK applications run as superuser use the old default GNOME, regardless of whether I run them with `kdesudo`, `gksudo`, or `sudo` on a terminal.  For example, here's `gedit` run as superuser on top, and under my normal user account on the bottom:
[image: gedit run as superuser and normal user on KDE]

Strangely, Qt applications run with `kdesudo` display the default Oxygen styling but use my settings when run with `sudo` on a terminal.

Is there any way to configure the stying GTK applications use when run as superuser on KDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Create a `~root/.gtkrc-2.0` with contents:

```
gtk-theme-name = "QtCurve"
```